# Druid: Firehose to import records from database

Tags: druid

Unlike default examples where we have firehose(s) for importing rows from csv, tsv etc, do we have one so we can import records from database and insert into druid? Any thoughts?

Here is what I was thinking -

```
"firehose": {
    "type" : "database",
        "datasource" : {
                 "connectURI" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
                 "user" : "druid",
                 "password" : "xyz123"
        },
        "query" : "select * from table"
        "frequency" : "P1M"
}
```

We can possibly extend it to get connection via jndi datasource and few others. Does this sort of implementation have any issues?

Comment: May be it would be simpler to export from the database into csv file and then use the usual way?

Comment: Sure, but size of the data is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
How about this idea? It's custom firehose for jdbc ingestion.
In this case, only supports one time query ingestion. 
https://github.com/sirpkt/druid/tree/jdbc_firehose/extensions-contrib/jdbc-firehose
This is code snippet. Using DBI library try to get result set from existing database server.
```

```
  public Firehose connect(final MapInputRowParser parser) throws IOException, ParseException, IllegalArgumentException
  {
    if (columns != null) {
      verifyParserSpec(parser.getParseSpec(), columns);
    }

    final Handle handle = new DBI(
        connectorConfig.getConnectURI(),
        connectorConfig.getUser(),
        connectorConfig.getPassword()
    ).open();

    final String query = makeQuery(columns);

    final ResultIterator<InputRow> rowIterator = handle
        .createQuery(query)
        .map(
            new ResultSetMapper<InputRow>()
            {
              List<String> queryColumns = (columns == null) ? Lists.<String>newArrayList(): columns;

              @Override
              public InputRow map(
                  final int index,
                  final ResultSet r,
                  final StatementContext ctx
              ) throws SQLException
              {
                try {
                  if (queryColumns.size() == 0)
                  {
                    ResultSetMetaData metadata = r.getMetaData();
                    for (int idx = 1; idx <= metadata.getColumnCount(); idx++)
                    {
                      queryColumns.add(metadata.getColumnName(idx));
                    }
                    Preconditions.checkArgument(queryColumns.size() > 0,
                        String.format("No column in table [%s]", table));
                    verifyParserSpec(parser.getParseSpec(), queryColumns);
                  }
                  ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> builder = new ImmutableMap.Builder();
                  for (String column: queryColumns) {
                    builder.put(column, r.getObject(column));
                  }
                  return parser.parse(builder.build());

                } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                  throw new SQLException(e);
                }
              }
            }
        ).iterator();
```